# How do you avoid the following error: "Automation Error. It is illegal to call out while inside message filter "?

Tags: .net, vb6, error-handling

I am currently working on a vb6 application that calls a .net application.
However once the .net application is open and you click back on the vb6 application, you get the following error:

"Automation Error. It is illegal to call out while inside message filter"

I've tried to debug this in the vb6 IDE setting it to break on all errors, but it justs opens the error dialog box straight away.

Does anyone have an example to get around this?

Comment: How do you call .NET application? If it is some kind of out-of-process COM/ActiveX object, then such behavior is by design - you can't run another code in caller before callee returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, you can not make out of process COM calls (to an ActiveX EXE, etc) while in a subclass handler.
You'll need to refactor the code to make that call outside the handler, e.g. in a timer with a 1ms interval. If you show some code that you're using, we can help further.

Comment: `Command1_Click` *is* a "subclass handler" -- how come? I've seen the same error in inter-thread situations, so ActiveX EXEs are not necassaryly involved.

Comment: There was no mention of a normal click event. I've only seen it with subclassing and OoP COM and so I answered as such. There may well be other causes, for which there is space below to mention. Having said that, the timer approach may still be a workable solution though.